# cascade delete EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm new with entity framework code first, so I will like to ask the following:
I have this entity:

```
public class ConfigurationSetEntity
{
   public virtual List<IsapreEntity> Isapres { get; set; }
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public virtual string Culture { get; set; }
}
```

and also this:

```
public class IsapreEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string IsapreName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IsapreOf")]
    [Required]
    public virtual string CultureId { get; set; }

    public virtual ConfigurationSetEntity IsapreOf { get; set; }
}
```

when I use ConfigurationSetEntity.Isapres.Remove(entity) I get an DbEntityValidationException, this is the code for the remove:

```
IsapreModel original = this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentIsapre);
ConfigurationSetEntity defaultConfigSet = dbContext.ConfigurationSets.Find(Constants.DefaultConfigurationSetId);
IsapreEntity originalEntity =defaultConfigSet.Isapres.Find(e => e.IsapreName==original.Isapre);
defaultConfigSet.Isapres.Remove(originalEntity);

try
{
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //This is where I catch the exception
}
defaultConfigSet.Isapres.Add(new IsapreEntity { IsapreName = currentIsapre.Isapre });
try
{
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

And this is the exception:

```
"The IsapreOf field is required."
```

What I want to do is to use `ConfigurationSetEntity.Isapres.Remove(entity)` and have entity removed from the `IsapreEntities` table and from the list.
Can some one please explain why the error and/or how can I achieve my intended purpose?

Comment: Please show the code block where you do the remove and the exception message if you want help.

Comment: Have already modified the post with code and exception